# How to put ignored folder into release archive on GitHub?

Tags: jquery, github, release, gitignore

In [jQuery’s releases](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/releases) on GitHub there is a `/dist` folder that ignored in [.gitignore](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/.gitignore#L11).

Archives look like automatically generated and not uploaded.

They have special URL:

`github.com/%owner%/%repo%/archive/%tag%.zip`

...while uploaded files have a different address format:

`github.com/%owner%/%repo%/releases/download/%tag%/%fileName%`

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at an example tag on GitHub, you'll see the `dist` directory included:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/1.11.1-beta1

So the archive is automatically created from the tag, which includes the dist directory. It appears that the jquery/jquery project includes a release process which includes the dist directory when tagging and releasing a new version.

Ignored files can be added using the `-f` option when calling `git add`:

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html